# React - WP Gutenberg Block - Save Function Crashes - Invalid valid hook call

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-hooks, wordpress-gutenberg

Been scratching my head with this one and not sure what's going wrong. When I try to import react-bootstrap Carousel within the 'save' block I get an error of -

***Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.***

I've checked react and react-dom are consistent versions, I'm using Wordpress 6.2.

index.jsx

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import './style.scss';

import Edit from './edit';
import Save from './save';

import json from '../block.json'

const { name } = json;

registerBlockType(name, {
  edit: Edit,
  save: Save
});
```

edit.jsx

```
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks, useInnerBlocksProps, InspectorControls} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';

const Edit = ( props ) => {

const {
    attributes: { mediaURLfirst, mediaURLsecond, mediaURLthird},
    setAttributes,
} = props;

const blockProps = useBlockProps();
const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps(
    {},
    { allowedBlocks: ['core/paragraph', 'core/heading', 'core/image'] }
);

 return (
    
    <div {...blockProps}>

      <Carousel>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img src={mediaURLfirst} className="d-block w-100" alt="First slide" />
        </Carousel.Item>

        ....

     </Carousel>

    </div>
  );
};
export default Edit;
```

save.jsx

```
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks, useInnerBlocksProps, RichText } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';

const Save = ( props ) => {

  const { attributes: { mediaURLfirst, mediaURLsecond, mediaURLthird},
} = props;

const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps.save();


return (
    <div {...blockProps}>
      <Carousel>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img src={mediaURLfirst} className="d-block w-100" alt="First slide" />
        </Carousel.Item>

        ....

      </Carousel>
    </div>

  );
};
export default Save;
```